# Attach an executable and jar file in xcode project and call it from within the project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, shell

I am trying to run a shell command which uses a third-party tool "`apktool`" from within my macOS Xcode project.

I don't have any way to ensure that Apktool is already installed on the user computer, so I decided to attach the jar file and the executable for `apktool` with my Xcode project.

This is the link to `apktool` installation: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

I tried putting both the jar and executable into the assets folder of the project, but I am not sure how to find the path to that executable and successfully execute it from within my code.

I am using the following method to run shell to execute the `apktool` installation.

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    //task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    
    task.launchPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("apktool")
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

The two main confusions right now are:

> 1. How to get the path to that executable from the assets folder. Is assets the correct place to put the jar and executable file?
> 2. How to run shell command to successfully make use of that executable into my project.

Comment: "assets folder" Did you mean `Resources`? As in `App.app/Contents/Resources`?

Comment: @Alexander I mean the actual assets folder where you can drag and drop images or files from your Xcode. Assets.xcassets folder. I am not sure if this is similar to the resources folder.

Comment: No, `xcassets` is pretty specialized towards images, icons, colours, etc., which then gets optimized/slimmed/compressed by Xcode/Apple. Copying it into the resource folder of your app bundle would make more sense, IMO. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html and